What was the highest sustained acceleration that a spacecraft crew experienced in The Expanse?
I reviewed a few of the other answers on this site (see: here and here, but wasn't able to find an answer to my question.
Books or TV series - either is ok.
I'm interested in determining what hard sci-fi writers feel is a reasonable upper limit for human-survivable acceleration with near-term future technologies, such as acceleration couches, g-suits, drugs, and respirators. Therefore, if there is another sci-fi series that's high on the hardness scale (besides The Expanse) that also delves into this topic, I'd find that interesting too.

This answer has already addressed various maxima seen in the books - What is the acceleration for different crews in the Expanse?.

@valorium, yes some good info in that answer.

There are aerospace researchers who have spent their lives researching exactly these limits. Wouldn't you rather look into that than speculation from fiction authors, who in the end likely care more about a good story?
